# Sum of even numbers in an Javascript array?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, sum, fibonacci

Trying to sum the even numbers of the fibonacci sequence. Why is it not summing all of the numbers together and just using the last number? How can I sum all of the even numbers together? 
Here's my code:

```
function fibonacciSum(){
    var i;
    var fib = new Array ();

    fib[0] = 0;  
    fib[1] = 1; 
        for(i=2; i<=10; i++){  
            fib[i] = fib[i-2] + fib[i-1]; 
            var number = parseInt(fib[i]);   
            var sum = 0;  
            if (number % 2 == 0) {  
                var result = sum += fib[i];  
                }  
         }  
    console.log(result);   
}
```

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22240354/javascript-looping-through-fibonacci-numbers-and-testing-for-even-numbers.

Comment: My suspicion is that this user is an alias of the user who posted the two questions above.

Comment: actually Im a different person. I looked at those to try and solve mine.

Comment: FYI - I posted the same answer as the accepted one 5 minutes before it was posted, is there any reason you accepted his?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare sum and result outside for loop. Try this:

```
function fibonacciSum(){
    var i;
    var fib = new Array ();

    fib[0] = 0;  
    fib[1] = 1;
    var sum = 0; 
    var result = 0; 
    for(i=2; i<=10; i++){  
        fib[i] = fib[i-2] + fib[i-1]; 
        var number = fib[i]; 
        if (number % 2 == 0) {  
            result = sum += fib[i];  
        }  
     }  
    console.log(result);   
}
```

Comment: No need to do parseInt(). Elements in fib array are integers.

Answer (score 3):

`var sum = 0;`

This is in your loop resetting the `sum` on every iteration. It has to be outside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

In your solution, each run of the for loop resets "sum" with the line:
`var sum = 0;`. Set it to 0 outside the loop.

```
function fibonacciSum(){
    var i;
    var fib = new Array ();
    fib[0] = 0;  
    fib[1] = 1; 
    var sum = 0;
        for(i=2; i<=10; i++){  
            fib[i] = fib[i-2] + fib[i-1]; 
                var number = parseInt(fib[i]);    
                if (number % 2 == 0) {  
                    var result = sum += fib[i];  
                }  
         }  
    console.log(result);   
}
```